# strpos vs preg_match - memory and resource differences

Tags: php, resources, preg-match, strpos

There have been questions asking which is faster `strpos` or `preg_match`, but I'm interested in knowing which uses the least memory and CPU resources.

I want to check a line for one of 5 matches:

```
if (strpos($key, 'matchA') !== false || strpos($key, 'matchB') !== false || strpos($key, 'matchC') !== false || strpos($key, 'matchD') !== false || strpos($key, 'matchE') !== false) 

if (preg_match("~(matchA|matchB|matchC|matchD|matchE)~i",$key, $match))
```

What is the best way to do this using the least strain on the server?

Comment: This question suits better for code review forum. http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: OK Thanks - I'll post it on there.  Thanks

Comment: I think this question is valid on SO as well, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jeffrey Friedl's Mastering Regular Expressions said that using the built in non-regex functions like `strpos()` and `str_match()` is always better and faster than using `preg_match()` (assuming you're using the preg suite) given that your **match text is not a pattern**.

Answer (score 1):

I was curious so I wrote the following short script:

```
<?php

$keys = [
    "veryshort",
    "veryvertlongstringhereveryvertlongstringhereveryvertlongstringhereveryvertlongstringhereveryvertlongstringhereveryvertlongstringhere",
    "shortstringwithmatchBintheresomewhere",
    uniqid("",true).uniqid("",true).uniqid("",true).uniqid("",true).uniqid("",true).uniqid("",true).uniqid("",true).uniqid("",true).uniqid("",true) //just random stuff 
];
$ops = 1000000;

foreach ($keys as $key) {
    $mt = microtime(true);


    for ($i = 0;$i < $ops;$i++) {
        $bool = strpos($key, 'matchA') !== false || strpos($key, 'matchB') !== false || strpos($key, 'matchC') !== false || strpos($key, 'matchD') !== false || strpos($key, 'matchE') !== false;
    }

    $mtEnd = microtime(true);
    echo PHP_EOL."String $key".PHP_EOL;
    echo "StrPos".PHP_EOL;
    echo "Total time: ".($mtEnd-$mt).PHP_EOL;
    echo "Average time: ".($mtEnd-$mt)/$ops.PHP_EOL;

    $mt = microtime(true);
    for ($i = 0;$i < $ops;$i++) {
        $bool = preg_match("~(matchA|matchB|matchC|matchD|matchE)~i",$key, $match);
    }
    $mtEnd = microtime(true);
    echo "preg_match".PHP_EOL;
    echo "Total time: ".($mtEnd-$mt).PHP_EOL;
    echo "Average time: ".($mtEnd-$mt)/$ops.PHP_EOL;

}
```

This is the result I got.

```
String veryshort
StrPos
Total time: 0.4722261428833
Average time: 4.722261428833E-7
preg_match
Total time: 0.39836096763611
Average time: 3.9836096763611E-7

String veryvertlongstringhereveryvertlongstringhereveryvertlongstringhereveryvertlongstringhereveryvertlongstringhereveryvertlongstringhere
StrPos
Total time: 0.49143600463867
Average time: 4.9143600463867E-7
preg_match
Total time: 0.4594030380249
Average time: 4.594030380249E-7

String shortstringwithmatchBintheresomewhere
StrPos
Total time: 0.21032190322876
Average time: 2.1032190322876E-7
preg_match
Total time: 0.6224000453949
Average time: 6.224000453949E-7

String 577625b20d9632.50190056577625b20d9798.81879058577625b20d97e6.80533504577625b20d97f9.27988846577625b20d9806.94313293577625b20d9803.05317354577625b20d9818.68372474577625b20d9818.19126932577625b20d9825.80344644
StrPos
Total time: 0.50694704055786
Average time: 5.0694704055786E-7
preg_match
Total time: 0.4893159866333
Average time: 4.893159866333E-7
```

My interpretation on this is that running a single `preg_match` is faster than running multiple `strpos` because of function call overheads and additional comparisons per function, however, this does not seem to be the case when there is a match within your string, perhaps because when that happens the underlying regex state machine changes state and does more things (presumably).

I guess the answer is not as simple as "A is faster than B" but rather, "grab this code, put in your usual use cases in and see what's better for your particular case".

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this shows the time taken, not the resources used. Is there any way to see that ?

Comment: @Tom I'm not aware of anything that can tell you the resources used by a particular function (there's http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-peak-usage.php but that's probably not appropriate with the above code). All I can say is both preg_match and strpos accept arguments by value, meaning the will make a copy of each argument passed. Other than that strpos does not need any additional space, not sure about preg_match though, so you're probably worse off if you use 5 strpos instead of 1 preg_match resource wise.

Comment: I admire the effort put into this. This is interesting. I'm guessing on the 3rd test, preg_match continuous to search the other keywords even though it has already matched one hence the longer process time.